# quiz that has to give a final score based on radio button

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

I have developed a quiz that has to give a final score based on the answers given.

All the inputs are radio type and I thought I'd calculate the score:

1. if the radio input is checked
2. "score" attribute > which will then be added and then put the total in the `totalSum` span

this is my code:

```
<form class="multisteps_form" name="richiestaform" id="richiestaform" action="">
  <div class="" id="richiestaform_responseok" style="display:none">
    <div class="cnt-risposta">
      <h3 class="richiesta-risposta text-white">Il tuo punteggio è: <span class="totalSum"></span></h3>
      <p class="text-white">Complimenti, sei un nativo digitale!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="richiestaform_responseko" style="display:none">
    <h3 class="richiesta-risposta text-white">Attenzione! La richiesta non è stata inoltrata.</h3>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none">
    <span request="yes" alt="txt_eMail" type="mail" checkmail=""></span>
    <input class="w-100 campoObb" id="txt_eMail" type="email" name="txt_eMail" placeholder="Email *" value="info@info.it" maxlength="200">
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------ Step-1 ------------------- -->
  <div class="multisteps_form_panel" style="display: block;">
    <div class="step_content d-flex justify-content-between pt-5 pb-2">
      <h4></h4>
      <span class="text-end text-uppercase">1 / 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_progress_bar">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:25%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_content">
      <div class="question_title py-5">
        <h2 class="text-white">Quanto ricorri alla carta per gestire le tue attività d'impresa?</h2>
        <p class="mb-0 text-white small">seleziona la risposta che ritieni più opportuna</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 form_items">
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_1" class="step_1 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_25ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_0.png" alt="meno del 30%">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">meno del 30%</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">utilizzo pochissima carta</p>
            <input for="opt_1" type="radio" name="stp_1_select_option" value="10" score="10">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_2" class="step_1 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_50ms active h-100 val-20">
            <div class="step_box_icon"><img src="assets/images/item-img/item_1.png" alt="tra il 30% e il 70%">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">tra il 30% e il 70%</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">utilizzo solo lo stretto necessario</p>
            <input for="opt_2" type="radio" name="stp_1_select_option" value="tra il 30% e il 70%" score="20">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_3" class="step_1 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_100ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon"><img src="assets/images/item-img/item_2.png" alt="oltre il 70%">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">oltre il 70%</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">uso solo carta</p>
            <input for="opt_3" type="radio" name="stp_1_select_option" value="oltre il 70%" score="30">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_btn pt-5 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button type="button" class="prev_btn text-uppercase" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="display: none;"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span> torna indietro</button>
      <button type="button" class="next_btn text-uppercase" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">prossima domanda <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------ Step-2 ------------------- -->
  <div class="multisteps_form_panel">
    <div class="step_content d-flex justify-content-between pt-5 pb-2">
      <h4></h4>
      <span class="text-end text-uppercase">2 / 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_progress_bar">
      <div class="progress rounded-pill">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:50%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_content">
      <div class="question_title py-5">
        <h2 class="text-white">Utilizzi già degli applicativi digitali/software in azienda?</h2>
        <p class="mb-0 text-white small">seleziona la risposta che ritieni più opportuna</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 d-flex row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 form_items">
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_4" class="step_2 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_25ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_4.png" alt="quasi nulla">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Quasi nulla</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">non uso nessun applicativo</p>
            <input for="opt_4" type="radio" name="stp_2_select_option" value="Quasi nulla" score="10">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_5" class="step_2 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_50ms h-100 active val-20">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_5.png" alt="solo programmi elementari">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">
            Solo programmi elementari
            </span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">posta elettronica, word, xls...</p>
            <input for="opt_5" type="radio" name="stp_2_select_option" value="Solo programmi elementari" score="20">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_6" class="step_2 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_100ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_6.png" alt="Utilizzo un gestionale specifico">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Utilizzo un gestionale specifico</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">adatto alla mia azienda</p>
            <input for="opt_6" type="radio" name="stp_2_select_option" value="Utilizzo un gestionale specifico" score="30">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_btn pt-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="prev_btn text-uppercase" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span> torna indietro</button>
      <button type="button" class="next_btn text-uppercase" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">prossima domanda <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------ Step-3 ------------------- -->
  <div class="multisteps_form_panel">
    <div class="step_content d-flex justify-content-between pt-5 pb-2">
      <h4></h4>
      <span class="text-end text-uppercase">3 / 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_progress_bar">
      <div class="progress rounded-pill">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:75%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_content">
      <div class="question_title py-5">
        <h2 class="text-white">Quanto sei soddisfatto degli applicativi/programmi che utilizzi?</h2>
        <p class="mb-0 text-white small">seleziona la risposta che ritieni più opportuna</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 form_items">
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_7" class="step_3 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_25ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_7.png" alt="Soddisfano le mie necessità">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Soddisfano le mie necessità</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">non ho bisogno di altro</p>
            <input for="opt_7" type="radio" name="stp_3_select_option" value="Soddisfano le mie necessità" checked="">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_8" class="step_3 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_50ms active h-100 val-20">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_8.png" alt="mi aiutano ma avrei bisogno di qualcosa di meglio">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Mi aiutano...</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">avrei bisogno di qualcosa di meglio</p>
            <input for="opt_8" type="radio" name="stp_3_select_option" value="Mi aiutano">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_9" class="step_3 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_100ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_9.png" alt="non sono soddisfatto">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Non sono soddisfatto</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">mi piacerebbe che qualcuno mi proponesse delle soluzioni</p>
            <input for="opt_9" type="radio" name="stp_3_select_option" value="Non sono soddisfatto">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_btn pt-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="prev_btn text-uppercase" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span> torna indietro</button>
      <button type="button" class="next_btn text-uppercase" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">prossima domanda <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------ Step-4 ------------------- -->
  <div class="multisteps_form_panel">
    <div class="step_content d-flex justify-content-between pt-5 pb-2">
      <h4></h4>
      <span class="text-end text-uppercase">4 / 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_progress_bar">
      <div class="progress rounded-pill">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_content">
      <div class="question_title py-5">
        <h2 class="text-white">Quali sono secondo te le attività che potresti migliorare?</h2>
        <p class="mb-0 text-white small">seleziona la risposta che ritieni più opportuna</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 form_items">
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_10" class="step_4 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_100ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_10.png" alt="gestione del magazzino">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Gestione del magazzino</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">tracciamento di prodotti e ordini</p>
            <input for="opt_10" type="radio" name="stp_4_select_option" value="Gestione del magazzino">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_11" class="step_4 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_150ms h-100 active val-20">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_11.png" alt="trasferimento dati">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Trasferimento dati da / verso personale / collaboratori fuori sede</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">manutenzioni, installazioni...</p>
            <input for="opt_11" type="radio" name="stp_4_select_option" value="Trasferimento dati da / verso personale / collaboratori fuori sede">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label id="opt_12" class="step_4 d-flex flex-column text-center animate__animated animate__fadeInRight animate_200ms h-100">
            <div class="step_box_icon">
              <img src="assets/images/item-img/item_12.png" alt="Gestione accessi">
            </div>
            <span class="step_box_text pt-4">Gestione accessi</span>
            <p class="step_box_desc small">registrazione ospiti presso postazioni autonome o assistite da operatore</p>
            <input for="opt_12" type="radio" name="stp_4_select_option" value="Gestione accessi" checked="">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_btn pt-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="prev_btn text-uppercase" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span> torna indietro</button>
      <button type="button" class="next_btn text-uppercase bg-yellow" id="nextBtn"><input id="buttoninvia" type='submit' value='scopri il tuo punteggio' class="text-uppercase" onclick="checkRequest('IT','richiestaform',true,true);return false;"> <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="send" id="send" value="ok" >
  <input type="hidden" id="richiestaform_send" value="0" >
  <input type="hidden" name="keyfile" value="richiesta-form">
</form>
```

How could I do it via jQuery?

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Without some kind of hint we can't really be sure what you're trying to do, or how it would be done best. Plus, it looks like all of your questions only have one possible answer anyway.

Comment: Bit hard to work with the little you've provided, and some attempt is usually required, so not a full answer.  Not all radio's have a score=, and these *should* be `data-score=`. But with what's provided:   `$(":radio:checked").map((i, e) => ($(e).attr("score") || "0") * 1).get().reduce((tot, val) => tot + val, 0)`  https://jsfiddle.net/9os7jzmg/

Answer (score 0):

You have provided too much unnecessary HTML.

- Please, next time be considerate and post only the MINIMAL code needed to reproduce your problem.
- Also, please remove parts of code that will not appear here (e.g., `assets/*` -> this is local to your server, here they just cause a bunch of `404 (Not Found)` errors)

This snippet does not use `jQuery`, only simple JS.
Open the console to see what would've been submitted when you click on `submit`.

```js
const pageData = [
  {
    label: "Page 1",
    questions: [
      ["question 1 1", 10],
      ["question 1 2", 20],
      ["question 1 3", 30],
      ["question 1 4", 40],
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Page 2",
    questions: [
      ["question 2 1", 10],
      ["question 2 2", 20],
      ["question 2 3", 30],
      ["question 2 4", 40],
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Page 3",
    questions: [
      ["question 3 1", 10],
      ["question 3 2", 20],
      ["question 3 3", 30],
      ["question 3 4", 40],
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Page 4",
    questions: [
      ["question 4 1", 10],
      ["question 4 2", 20],
      ["question 4 3", 30],
      ["question 4 4", 40],
    ]
  },
]

const getQuestionHtml = (question, pageLabel) => {
  const isChecked = question.selected ? `checked` : ''
  return `
    <div>
      <label>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="${pageLabel}" ${isChecked}/>
        ${question.selected} - 
        ${question.text}
      </label>
    </div>
  `
}

const getRadioGroupHtml = (page) => {
  const inputs = page.questions.map(q => getQuestionHtml(q, page.label)).join('')
  return `
    <div class="page">
      ${inputs}
    </div>
  `
}

const setRadioEventListeners = (pages) => {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-input')
  inputs.forEach((input, idx) => {
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
      setQuestionVal({
        pageIdx: pages.currentPageIdx,
        questionIdx: idx,
        data: pages,
      })
      setTotal(pages)
    })
  })
}

const setTotal = (pages) => {
  const totalContainer = document.getElementById('total')
  totalContainer.innerHTML = pages.total
}

const updatePage = ({ container, data }) => {
  container.innerHTML = getRadioGroupHtml(data.currentPage)
  setRadioEventListeners(data)
  setTotal(data)
}

const pageContainer = document.getElementById('form-page')

const getQuestion = ({ text, val }) => {
  const _id = "" + Date.now() + Math.random()
  const _text = text
  const _val = val
  let _selected = false
  return {
    get text() {
      return _text
    },
    get id() {
      return _id
    },
    get val() {
      return _val
    },
    get selected() {
      return _selected
    },
    set selected(val) {
      _selected = val
    },
    setSelected(val) {
      this.selected = val
    }
  }
}

const getFormPages = (pageData) => {
  return pageData.map(({ label, questions }) => {
    return {
      label,
      questions: questions.map(([q, v]) => getQuestion({ text: q, val: v }))
    }
  })
}

const data = getFormPages(pageData)
const setQuestionVal = ({ pageIdx, questionIdx, val = true, data }) => {
  data.currentPage.questions.forEach((question, idx) => idx == questionIdx ? question.setSelected(val) : question.setSelected(!val))
}

const getQuestionnaire = (pages) => {
  let _current = 0
  return {
    get hasNext() {
      return _current < pages.length - 1
    },
    get hasPrev() {
      return 0 < _current
    },
    next() {
      if (this.hasNext) {
        _current += 1
      }
    },
    prev() {
      if (this.hasPrev) {
        _current -= 1
      }
    },
    get currentPage() {
      return pages[_current]
    },
    get currentPageIdx() {
      return _current
    },
    toNextPage() {
      this.next()
      return this.currentPage
    },
    toPrevPage() {
      this.prev()
      return this.currentPage
    },
    get total() {
      return pages
        .map(p => p.questions)
        .flat()
        .filter(q => q.selected)
        .reduce((a, c) => a + c.val, 0)
    },
  }
}

const formPages = getQuestionnaire(data)

const updateNavBtnState = (btn, state) => {
  btn.disabled = !state
}

const updateNavBtns = (btnPrev, btnNext) => (data) => {
  updateNavBtnState(btnNext, data.hasNext)
  updateNavBtnState(btnPrev, data.hasPrev)
}

const btnNext = document.getElementById("btn-next")
const btnPrev = document.getElementById("btn-prev")

const updateNav = updateNavBtns(btnPrev, btnNext)

const addNavEventListeners = (btnPrev, btnNext, data) => {
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    data.toPrevPage()
    updateNav(data)
    updatePage({
      container: pageContainer,
      data: formPages,
    })
  })
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    data.toNextPage()
    updateNav(data)
    updatePage({
      container: pageContainer,
      data: formPages,
    })
  })
}

updateNav(formPages)
addNavEventListeners(btnPrev, btnNext, formPages)
updatePage({
  container: pageContainer,
  data: formPages,
})

const form = document.getElementById('questionnaire-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('%c FORM TOTAL : ', 'color: red', formPages.total)
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Questionnaire</div>
<div class="page-container">
<form id="questionnaire-form">
  <div id="form-page"></div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <button id="btn-prev" type="button"><< PREV PAGE</button>
    <button id="btn-next" type="button">NEXT PAGE >></button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<div>
  TOTAL: <span id="total">0</span>
</div>
</div>
```